# Detecting when the Job is STOPPING in a FlatFileItemReader custom bufferedReader instance

Tags: spring-batch

How would one detect when the Job has been signaled to stop from within the FlatFileItemReader bufferedFileReader that was created using the configured custom BufferedFileReaderFactory bean. This custom bufferedFileReader tails the file and waits for more input indefinitely so the Job STOPPING status isn't being detected as the code is blocked outside the Spring Batch framework.

I can do this with a Step1->Tasklet->Step1 flow loop that does a Thread.sleep in the Tasklet but the nature of this constantly growing file means I'll be hitting EOF every couple of seconds and generating a huge amount of StepExecution rows in the database.

```java
public class TailingBufferedReaderFactory implements BufferedReaderFactory {
  @Override
  public BufferedReader create(Resource resource, String encoding) throws IOException {
    return new TailingBufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), encoding));
  }
}

public class TailingBufferedReader extends BufferedReader implements JobExecutionListener {
  private JobExecution jobExecution;

  public TailingBufferedReader(Reader in) {
    super(in);
  }

  @Override
  public String readLine() throws IOException {
    while (!jobExecution.isStopping()) {  //The elusive Job Execution status check
      var line = super.readLine();
      if (line == null) {
        Thread.sleep(waitDurationMillis);
        continue;
      }
      return line;
    }
    return null;
  }

// Ideally something like this configured on the Job
  @Override
  public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    this.jobExecution = jobExecution;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {}
}
```

Comment: I wonder why would one need to do that. It is the step that drives the reader and not the other way around. So if you instruct the step to stop, it will stop reading. The reader is not aware (and should not be aware) of when it should read or stop reading.

Comment: The goal is to find a Tail type file reading solution for Spring Batch.  I'm trying to short circuit the BufferedReader that is waiting for an extended, possibly infinite, duration of time for the next line of the file to be ready to read so that control can return up the call stack.